# how to search for a string in all table Columns in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

how can i search for a string in all the tables columns ?

any help please ?

this is my database creation method

thanks

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_TITLE
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_COUNTRY_ID
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_DESCRIPTION
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_IDP
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_CATEGORYP
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_CREATED_P
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_CREATED_P2
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_CREATED_BY
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_KEYS
                + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_READ_BY
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DIR 
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CITY 
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LINK + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use LIKE query and loop for each single column

like this :

```
    public Cursor searchDB(String query) { 
    return db.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_COLUMN1, KEY_COLUMN2,
    KEY_COLUMN3 }, KEY_COLUMN1 + " LIKE" + "'%" + query + "%' OR " + KEY_COLUMN2 + 
    " LIKE" + "'%" + query + "%' OR " + KEY_COLUMN3 + " LIKE" + "'%" + query + "%'", 
    null, null, null, null, null); 
}
```

hope that's help